# I have a basic tensorflow model in python I want to convert it to onnx file

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, onnx

I have basic model in python tensorflow I want to save it to onnx file how can I do this. I have tried using `onnx.save` function I am getting error.

```py
File "tenserflowbase.py", line 21, in <module> onnx.save(trained_model,'model.onxx') 
File "C:\Users\Parag_IK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\onnx\__init__.py", line 184, in save_model proto = write_external_data_tensors(proto, basepath)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
File "C:\Users\Parag_IK\Anaconda3\lib\site packages\onnx\external_data_helper.py", line 225, in write_external_data_tensors                                               
for tensor in _get_all_tensors(model):                                                                                                                              
File "C:\Users\Parag_IK\Anaconda3\lib\site packages\onnx\external_data_helper.py", line 170, in _get_initializer_tensors                                                 
for initializer in onnx_model_proto.graph.initializer:                                                                                                              
AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'graph'**
```

My code is below:

```py
import onnx
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)   

mar_budget = np.array([60, 80,  100  , 30, 50, 20, 90,  10],  dtype=float)
subs_gained = np.array([160, 200, 240, 100, 140, 80, 220, 60],  dtype=float)

for i, c in enumerate(mar_budget):
  print("{} Market budget = {} new subscribers gained".format(c, subs_gained[i]))


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(mar_budget, subs_gained, 
   random_state=42, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2)

layer_0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])
model = tf.keras.Sequential([layer_0])
model = tf.keras.Sequential([layer_0])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))

trained_model = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=False)      

onnx.save(trained_model,'model.onxx')

print("Finished training the model")   
print(model.predict([80.0]))
```

Comment: `model.fit` returns a history of your training process, not the fit model. Just pass `model` to your `onnx.save()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think if I am not wrong, in order to use `onnx.save()`, the model should create the graph in `onnx` functions.

So I would suggest using the `tf2onnx` library, which has a function convert the tf session graph into onnx graph.

```py
onnx_graph = tf2onnx.tfonnx.process_tf_graph(sess.graph, ...)
```

For example a full code would be:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tf2onnx

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 3], name="input")
    x_ = tf.add(x, x)
    _ = tf.identity(x_, name="output")
    onnx_graph = tf2onnx.tfonnx.process_tf_graph(sess.graph, input_names=["input:0"], output_names=["output:0"])
    model_proto = onnx_graph.make_model("test")
    with open("/tmp/model.onnx", "wb") as f:
        f.write(model_proto.SerializeToString())
```

Hope this helps.

Reference: [tensorflow-onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx)

Comment: It is not yet supported in tensorflow 2.0 according to this [issue](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/issues/684) on github.

Comment: graph=tf.Graph()
    tf2onnx.tfonnx.process_tf_graph(graph, 'x.onnx')   I am using this code but on getting any x.onnx file and not getting any error as well

Comment: @ParagJain. See the answer again. `tf2onnx.tfonnx.process_tf_graph` will process the graph, you cannot use it to save into `onnx` file, you need literately `f.write()` out the graph.